# Does anyone know what order Tough the manga goes in?

Tags: koukou-tekkenden-tough

In the story/manga called "Tough", I know that the first series when he is 17 goes first, but after that I am lost.

Also could someone tell me the names of the series and possibly state a source for credibility? I know 2 are called "Oton" and "Koukou Tekkenden Tough".

[image]
[image]

Comment: As far as I can discern [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_(manga)), *Kōkō Tekken-den Tough* is first, *Tough* is second, and *Odon* is a spin-off series.